# How to use the same class jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-animate

You have to see the effect to know what I mean.

http://jsfiddle.net/VS8tQ/28

I couldn't use the same class in jQuery because I could not reach the desired effect, so I made the animation with 2 classes.

Can anyone tell me how can I use just one class to achieve the same effect?

Comment: I've updated my code. Thank you all for your comments. 

http://jsfiddle.net/VS8tQ/34/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need a nested loop for this:

```
$(".section").each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VS8tQ/29/

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the solution you're looking for ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/VS8tQ/32/)):

```
$("p").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);

$(".divSection").each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(100 * i).css('display', 'block').animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 0).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            marginLeft: "+=10px"
        }, 200)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely correct and no need to write it two times. Just use jQuery match for class name `'section'` as below:

```
$("p").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);    
$("div[class^='section']").each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this)
            .delay(100 * i)
            .css('display', 'block')
            .animate({opacity: 0}, 0)       
            .animate({opacity: 1, marginLeft: "+=10px"}, 200)
    });
});
```

`"div[class^='section']"` selects all classes that starts with 'section' (like section1,section2..).

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with Daff's solution, it is simpler, but you gave us a nice hint there (for other problems).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VS8tQ/30/

```
$("p").animate({opacity: 0}, 0);


$(".divSection1 *").each(function(i) {
    taDa(this, i)
});

$(".divSection2 *").each(function(i) {
    taDa(this, i)
});

function taDa(obj, i) {
    $(obj)
        .delay(100 * i)
        .css('display', 'block')
        .animate({opacity: 0}, 0)       
        .animate({opacity: 1, marginLeft: "+=10px"}, 200);
}
```